# How to customize Genexus Slide Navgation menu

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I am making an SD app with Genexus. I am using slide navigation but my menu seems very different from the Android native ones. I would like to know if there's a way to customize it, like setting line height, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Cristianne,

I think you may be using a Dashboard for your Slide Menu.
The Dashboard is very limited and only supports a List of Items.

However, you can create a custom Slide Menu by creating a simple 'SD Panel' and setting it as Main Program for your application (instead of the Dashbord object).

Take a look into this [Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.futbolx.ligamx&hl=en).
It's a GeneXus Application with a full custom Slide Menu.